# Create a list composed of one string per regex substitution?

Tags: python

I'm looking for the fastest way to perform a regex substitution for each occurrence of some set of letters and throw all the results into a list or set. **For example, say I want to replace every occurrence of 'hi' in the string 'hi foo hi bar hi ho' with 'yo':**

```
>>> replace_each('hi foo hi bar hi ho', 'hi', 'yo')
['yo foo hi bar hi ho', 'hi foo yo bar hi ho', 'hi foo hi bar yo ho']
```

I know I can do this just iterating through like:

```
def replace_each(some_string, to_replace, replace_with):
    solutions = []
    window = len(some_string)
    for idx in range(len(some_string)-window):
        if some_string[idx:idx+window] == to_replace
            solutions.append(some_string[:idx] + replace_with + some_string[idx+window:])
    return solutions
```

But, I have to do this a lot, so I'm looking for something faster, likely using regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
a = 'hi foo hi bar hi ho'
old_stuff = "hi"
new_stuff = "yo"

[a[:m.start()] + new_stuff + a[m.end():] for m in re.finditer(old_stuff, a)]
```

You could make a function around it to treat the part to find and the part to insert as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) :

```
import re
re.sub('hi','yo','hi foo hi bar hi ho')
```

or [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) :

```
'hi foo hi bar hi ho'.replace( 'hi', 'yo')
```

for replace all `hi` ! 
and for replace every occurrence of 'hi' you can do this :

```
>>> string='hi foo hi bar hi ho'
>>> sub_list=['yo'.join(l[i:i+2]) for i in range(len(l))]
>>> [re.sub('hi'.join(t.split('yo')),t,string) for t in sub_list]
['yo foo hi bar hi ho', 'hi foo yo bar hi ho', 'hi foo hi bar yo ho', 'hi foo hi bar hi ho']
```

Comment: See the example in the question. This is not answering the question. I want a new item in a list per substitution.